# Duplicate tasks created from workflow

Tags: workflow, tasks, duplicate

I have a workflow that creates a task when the task is modified.  The task is duplicated if the user goes in and modifies the task a second or third time.  How can I get the task to be created on the first modification and not again?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could add a step to your workflow to make sure a task is only created once. Add a hidden field to your list called something like "Task created?". The default would be "No". Then your workflow could run as follows

- Item modified, workflow initiated
- Does "Task created?" = "Yes" then stop workflow. If "Task created?"="No", continue
- Create task
- Modify "Task created?" to "Yes"

Comment: Did this work for you?